# How to write this MYSQL query to Mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have one query which is written in mysql but i don't know how to write exact same query in mongodb using aggregates. I tried couple of time but didn't working.

**Here's the MYSQL query:**

```
    "INSERT INTO `dailyprice`( `coin_id`, `avg_price_usd`, `avg_price_btc`, `24h_volume_usd`, `market_cap_usd`, `high`, `low`, `open`, `close`, `date`) SELECT coin_id, AVG( price_usd ) as avg_price_usd, AVG( price_btc ) as avg_price_btc, 24h_volume_usd, market_cap_usd,   
MAX( price_usd ) as high, 
MIN( price_usd ) as low,
SUBSTRING_INDEX( GROUP_CONCAT( CAST( price_usd AS CHAR ) ORDER BY last_updated ASC ) ,  ',', 1 ) AS open, 
SUBSTRING_INDEX( GROUP_CONCAT( CAST( price_usd AS CHAR ) ORDER BY last_updated DESC ) ,  ',', 1 ) AS close,
'".$today." 00:00:00' as last_updated
FROM hourlyprice
WHERE DATE(last_updated) = DATE('".$today."')
GROUP BY coin_id
ORDER BY coin_id";
```

**Here's the query that i tried but didn't working:**

```
const dummy = await DemoHourly.aggregate([
    { $match: {}},
    { "$project": {'slug': '$slug', 'avgPriceUsd': { $avg: "$priceUsd" }, 'avgPriceBtc': { $avg: "$priceBtc" }, 'volumeUsd24h': 'volumeUsd24h', 'marketcapUsd': 'marketcapUsd', 'high': { $max: "$priceUsd" }, 'low': { $min: "$priceUsd"}, 
    'open': { $substr: [ {sortBy: {'priceUsd': 1}}, ',', 1 ] }, 
    'close': { $substr: [ {sortBy: {'priceUsd': -1}}, ',', 1 ] }, 'date':  '$lastUpdated'}},
    {"$group" : {slug: "$slug"}},
    {"$sort": {slug: "$slug"}},
    {"$out": 'DemoDaily'},
]);
```

**Here's the sample data:**

```
> {"_id":{"$oid":"6138391e692a88047c9932ec"},"slug":"bitcoin-cash","lastUpdated":{"$date":{"$numberLong":"1630975170000"}},"priceUsd":{"$numberDecimal":"778.9255851705683"},"priceBtc":{"$numberDecimal":"0.01485905922493417"},"volumeUsd24h":{"$numberDecimal":"3525016631.607257"},"marketcapUsd":{"$numberDecimal":"14674188835.59815"},"__v":{"$numberInt":"0"}}
> {"_id":{"$oid":"6138391e692a88047c9932ea"},"slug":"bitcoin-cash","lastUpdated":{"$date":{"$numberLong":"1630973970000"}},"priceUsd":{"$numberDecimal":"780.8554493856429"},"priceBtc":{"$numberDecimal":"0.01484304670433461"},"volumeUsd24h":{"$numberDecimal":"3537000197.3464494"},"marketcapUsd":{"$numberDecimal":"14710545571.669245"},"__v":{"$numberInt":"0"}}
> {"_id":{"$oid":"6138391e692a88047c9932f0"},"slug":"bitcoin-cash","lastUpdated":{"$date":{"$numberLong":"1630977558000"}},"priceUsd":{"$numberDecimal":"780.4696085884976"},"priceBtc":{"$numberDecimal":"0.014836168061202465"},"volumeUsd24h":{"$numberDecimal":"3513387446.1191416"},"marketcapUsd":{"$numberDecimal":"14703276712.068815"},"__v":{"$numberInt":"0"}}
> {"_id":{"$oid":"6138391e692a88047c99343c"},"slug":"cardano","lastUpdated":{"$date":{"$numberLong":"1630977571000"}},"priceUsd":{"$numberDecimal":"2.82392726000138"},"priceBtc":{"$numberDecimal":"0.00005368083389917269"},"volumeUsd24h":{"$numberDecimal":"4552465993.487997"},"marketcapUsd":{"$numberDecimal":"90440076524.85124"},"__v":{"$numberInt":"0"}}
> {"_id":{"$oid":"6138391e692a88047c993435"},"slug":"cardano","lastUpdated":{"$date":{"$numberLong":"1630973370000"}},"priceUsd":{"$numberDecimal":"2.84529094801866"},"priceBtc":{"$numberDecimal":"0.000053960276764135886"},"volumeUsd24h":{"$numberDecimal":"4598913635.5157795"},"marketcapUsd":{"$numberDecimal":"91124281421.3245"},"__v":{"$numberInt":"0"}}
> {"_id":{"$oid":"6138391e692a88047c993440"},"slug":"cardano","lastUpdated":{"$date":{"$numberLong":"1630979977000"}},"priceUsd":{"$numberDecimal":"2.81250795077164"},"priceBtc":{"$numberDecimal":"0.000053563761437665065"},"volumeUsd24h":{"$numberDecimal":"4557377263.532797"},"marketcapUsd":{"$numberDecimal":"90074357756.09015"},"__v":{"$numberInt":"0"}}
```

Now, i want to insert data into another table

Anyone help will be much appreciated, thanks DemoDaily in which it will group by and sort by slug, also do lots of other stuffs like open and close which is the highest and lowest price of specific slug. You can check mysql query for more understanding.

Comment: could you provide sample data and you expected output ?

Comment: @mohammadNaimi please check i have edited my question!

Comment: so let me know you want just to put this data in another collection after these aggregations ?

Comment: Yes, it's all about transferring data from hourlytable to dailyprice table daily once using cron.

Comment: thank you im working on it please provide sample out put

Answer (score 0):

https://mongoplayground.net/p/Oak49MpxvCc
i create your query just I think the issue is in open and close fields , if there any problems tell me ,

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {}
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$slug",
      "avgPriceUsd": {
        $avg: "$priceUsd"
      },
      "avgPriceBtc": {
        $avg: "$priceBtc"
      },
      "high": {
        $max: "$priceUsd"
      },
      "low": {
        $min: "$priceUsd"
      },
      "orig": {
        $push: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$orig"
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "slug": "1",
      "avgPriceUsd": 1,
      "avgPriceBtc": 1,
      "volumeUsd24h": "$orig.volumeUsd24h",
      "marketcapUsd": "$orig.marketcapUsd",
      "high": 1,
      "low": 1,
      "date": "$orig.lastUpdated",
      "open": {
        "$substr": [
          "$low",
          0,
          1
        ]
      },
      "close": {
        "$substr": [
          "$high",
          0,
          1
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      slug: 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$out": "DemoDaily"
  }
])
```

Comment: It's showing this error: (node:8132) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoServerError: Exceeded memory limit for $group, but didn't allow external sort. Pass allowDiskUse:true to opt in. (i have already passed { allowDiskUse: true })

Comment: in mongodb connection option did you add ` { allowDiskUse: true }` ?

Comment: no i have added here in query. But where can i add in connection?

Comment: add like it, i tell wrong , should add to query like this 
`db.stocks.aggregate( [
      { $sort : { cusip : 1, date: 1 } }
   ],
   { allowDiskUse: true }
)`

Comment: as second argument of aggregate

Comment: Yes, added but still not working and showing same error

Comment: could you provide your `aggregate`

Comment: {
    "$project": {
   "slug": "1",
   "avgPriceUsd": 1,
   "avgPriceBtc": 1,
   "volumeUsd24h": "$orig.volumeUsd24h",
   "marketcapUsd": "$orig.marketcapUsd",
   "high": 1,
   "low": 1,
   "date": "$orig.lastUpdated",
   "open": {
     "$substr": [
    "$low",
    0,
    1
     ]
   },
   "close": {
     "$substr": [
    "$high",
    0,
    1
     ]
   }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
   slug: 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$out": "DemoDaily"
  }
   ], { allowDiskUse: true })

Comment: removed above part because of comment limit

Comment: did you check the results in mongoplay link ?

Comment: use this `DemoHourly.aggregate([]).allowDiskUse(true);`

Comment: just dont forget aggregation object

Comment: Yes, but there is no data grouped it's showing multiple records for single slug also  in open and close it's showing 0 and 1, but in our case we need actual value out of priceUSD

Comment: did you try `.allowDiskUse(true)` ?

Comment: {
    "$project": {
   "slug": "1",
   "avgPriceUsd": 1,
   "avgPriceBtc": 1,
   "volumeUsd24h": "$orig.volumeUsd24h",
   "marketcapUsd": "$orig.marketcapUsd",
   "high": 1,
   "low": 1,
   "date": "$orig.lastUpdated",
   "open": {
     "$substr": [
    "$low",
    0,
    1
     ]
   },
   "close": {
     "$substr": [
    "$high",
    0,
    1
     ]
   }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
   slug: 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$out": "DemoDaily"
  }
   ]).allowDiskUse(true);

Comment: try this 
`var aggregation = MyModel.aggregate(...); 
aggregation.options = { allowDiskUse: true }; 
aggregation.exec(function() {});`

Comment: First please check in mongoplay, there is no data grouped it's showing multiple records for single slug also in open and close it's showing 0 and 1, but in our case we need actual value out of priceUSD based on last_updated asc and desc order respectively